# Avoid Duplicates name

Tags: apex, trigger, duplicate-management

Here how can avoid duplicate lastname

```
trigger ContactNamesOnAccount on Contact (after update, after insert) {    
  Set<id> accIdList = new Set<id>();
  for(Contact con : Trigger.new){
    accIdList.add(con.accountid);
  }

  List<Account> accUpdateList = new List<Account>();
  List<String> names = new List<String>;

  for(Account acc : [Select id, Contact_Names__c, (Select LastName From Contacts) From Account Where Id In : accIdList]){
    for(Contact con : acc.contacts){
      if(con.LastName != null){
        /* add name to list */
        names.add(con.LastName);
      }
    }

    /* update name separating ', '  */
    acc.Contact_Names__c = String.join(names, ', ');;
    accUpdateList.add(acc);

    /* clear list to add new account contact names */
    names.clear();
  }    
  update accUpdateList;
}
```

Comment: Why not use standard salesforce feature [Duplicate Management](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sales_admin_duplicate_management) for this instead of custom code.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Do you want duplicates to be avoided in `Contact_Names__c` field ? or Do you want to avoid duplicate last names under same account ? Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/260852/edit) your question with the necessary details.

Comment: Yes i need to avoid duplicate Contact_Names__c  if i have two same names need to populate only one

Comment: @sree Updated the answer, that should work for you.

Comment: I've downvoted this question because you haven't made it clear what the problem is. "Duplicate last names" alone makes it sound like you're having trouble inserting `Contact` records. If Vijay's answer is right, a much better description of your problem would have been something like "I'm concatenating the last names of all Contacts related to a given Account. If two Contacts have the same last name, the concatenation contains that last name twice. How can I make it so that the concatenation only contains unique names?"

Answer (score 2):

As per your above comments, you want to avoid duplicates just in `Contact_Names__c` field of Account which is getting calculated in your trigger. So in order to do that, replacing `List<String>` with `Set<String>` should do the trick i.e. instead of using `List` to collect all the `Last Names`, you could use `Set` which will remove the duplicates as per its design.

Replace below line

```
List<String> names = new List<String>();
```

with

```
Set<String> names = new Set<String>();
```

So, once the duplicates are removed using `Set`, now you will need to concatenate these `last names` using comma. As you are using the `String's` `Join` method to do this, it won't accept `Set` as a parameter, hence you will have to convert this `Set` to `List` only for this operation which can be done as shown below.

When using `String.Join`, replace below code

```
acc.Contact_Names__c = String.join(names, ', ');
```

with

```
acc.Contact_Names__c = String.join(new List<String>(names), ', ');
```

So, your overall trigger would look something like this

```
trigger ContactNamesOnAccount on Contact (after update, after insert) {    
    Set<id> accIdList = new Set<id>();
    for(Contact con : Trigger.new){
        accIdList.add(con.accountid);
    }

    List<Account> accUpdateList = new List<Account>();
    Set<String> names = new Set<String>();

    for(Account acc : [Select id, Contact_Names__c, (Select LastName From Contacts) From Account Where Id In : accIdList]){
        for(Contact con : acc.contacts){
            if(con.LastName != null){
                /* add name to list */
                names.add(con.LastName);
            }
        }

        /* update name separating ', '  */
        acc.Contact_Names__c = String.join(new List<String>(names), ', ');
        accUpdateList.add(acc);

        /* clear list to add new account contact names */
        names.clear();
    }    
    update accUpdateList;
}
```

Comment: Hi 
if i updated some picklist value Active to InActive i need to remove perticular field

Comment: @sree if you have any further questions, I would recommend you to post a separate question for that.